# List of Salesforce objects those are File types like Document, StaticResource, Contents etc

Tags: metadata-api, attachment, files, static-resources, contentversion

I would like to know the list of Salesforce objects whose are based of FILE type. For example Document, Attachments, ContentVersions, Static Resources etc

I would like to see what more objects comes into these list. Any help on this question - will really helpful

Comment: You've already identified all of the main players. There are certainly a few less-common edge cases, like Classic Knowledge articles that contain File fields. What is your overall goal?

Comment: @DavidReed We are using Ownbackup tool to backup data of our full sandboxes. We are getting warnings for Attachments, Documents, ContentVersion, Static Resource data - that it's not backed up due to exceeding API download limit. And Ownbackup gives a checkbox to exclude FILE related objects from Backup - so before I configure this checkbox - I would like to know which objects comes in FILE related one.

Comment: You should ask OwnBackup exactly what that option does as it may not be the same as the answer you receive here.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this would be to examine the field metadata on all sObject types that you can access. You are looking for any field that has the `base64` data type. That would have a capacity to store file date (in theory at least).

This is true for:

- [ContentVersion.VersionData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentVersion.htm)
- [StaticResource.Body](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_StaticResource.htm)
- [Document.Body](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Document.htm)
- [Attachment.Body](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Attachment.htm)

I also found:

- [EmailCapture.RawMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_EmailCapture.htm?search_text=base64)
- [SControl.Binary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Scontrol.htm?search_text=base64) (SControls are deprecated)
- [EventLogFile.LogFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_EventLogFile.htm?search_text=base64) (read only)
- [MailmergeTemplate.Body](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_MailmergeTemplate.htm?search_text=base64)

This wasn't an exhaustive search though. You will likely need to use the [REST API describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_describe.htm) resource or the [Partner API describe web methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_list_describe.htm) for a more complete check. Or even an [Apex describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm).

Note that not every base64 field would represent a file. Especially one you could write to. But it will go a long way to finding the ones you can access in a particular org.

Comment: Daniel, what about the knowledge objects, are they base64 type too ?

Comment: The `Knowledge*` and related objects are their own "*special*" thing. They are so special that they have [different entity relationship diagrams for lightning and classic](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_knowledge.htm). I'd had guessed maybe `KnowledgeArticleVersion` or `Knowledge__kav`, but I didn't see any sign of binary data on them.